# SQL: How to show table column as row?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have table:

```
name quantity
abc     2
abc     3
abc     5
```

How can i query in mssql to see result in one row, like

```
abc 2 3 5
```

Thanks.

Comment: how many columns do you have in your desired result? 3 or 1 with values separated with space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this data in separate columns, then you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from 
(
  select name, quantity,
    'Qty_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by name order by quantity) as varchar(10)) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(quantity)
  for rn in (Qty_1, Qty_2, Qty_3)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59159/2). The result of the pivot is:

```
| NAME | QTY_1 | QTY_2 | QTY_3 |
--------------------------------
|  abc |     2 |     3 |     5 |
```

If you want this data in a single column, then you can use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF()`:

```
SELECT
     t1.Name,
     STUFF(
         (SELECT ' ' + cast(quantity as varchar(10))
          FROM yourtable t2
          WHERE t1.name = t2.name
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS List
FROM yourtable t1
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59159/4). The result of this query is:

```
| NAME |  LIST |
----------------
|  abc | 2 3 5 |
```

With the pivot function, if you have an unknown number of quantity values, then you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(rn) 
                    from
                    (
                      select 'Qty_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by name order by quantity) as varchar(10)) rn
                      from yourtable
                    ) t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select name, quantity,
                  ''Qty_''+cast(row_number() over(partition by name order by quantity) as varchar(10)) rn
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(quantity)
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59159/6)

Comment: Thanks. But will first example work if i have random number of rows `abc qty`?

Comment: @SergiiRechmp see my edit. If you are using the pivot function and the number of values it unknown then you will have to use dynamic sql

Comment: Thank you bluefeet, it works well. But its a bit hard query for me. Can you tell me please where i can type `where` clause (for example `where quantity >3`) and how to remove ordering from smallest value to biggest? I dont need it, seems i make bad example.

Comment: thanks for help. Sorry, i will be a bit shameless, but can you help me with one more thing: i wrote comment in [schema field](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88499/1)

Comment: @SergiiRechmp You just have to change the columns that you want to pivot -- see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88499/2

Comment: can you, please, look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435927/mssqlodbcphp-0-rows-in-result) thread? May be its about query?